# How to achieve this folding effect in android?

Tags: android, animation, view

This is the effect on the ios
Like the effect of paper folded
PaperFold for iOS :https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea : Android's UI is non skeuomorphic (unlike the iOS UI) and it is a very skeuomorphic effect.
If you look at an app like endomondo, that implements android design guidelines, but has a folding effect between its activities, it looks really out of place.

Comment: similar to [**PageCurl**](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/) effect ???

Comment: If your question related to page curl, then see this link: http://techie-manoj.com/?p=146

Comment: its not the same as page curl, its like a page fold scroll animation: https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS/raw/master/Screenshots/verticalfold.gif

Comment: @xman1234 did you find any way to get this effect in android?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use scale  animations on ImageViews that simulate the paper already folded. The scale effect would be used when you scroll through and expand the entire paper as you continue to scroll through the sets of images. Once you fully scroll through the paper ImageView and the animation is completed, you just kill the animation and have a normal view of a full page paper. Just make a separate folder for animation and inside that folder, create an XML file, select scale and play around with the attributes to test the best suitable effects for your animation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that helps to implement not accordion-like but another quite interesting folding effect: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzWGhp_NDTg

The explanation & code here http://cases.azoft.com/creating-paper-folding-animation-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foldable Layout Lib.
https://github.com/worldline/FoldableLayout